# Laravel routing slug error Bad Method Call Exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm trying to create a route with three slugs, which include category, brand name and product name.

web.php

```
Route::get('/shop/{category:slug}/{brand:slug}/{product:slug}', [ProductController::class, 'index']);
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Brand;
use App\Category;
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Category $category, Brand $brand, Product $product)
    {
        $product = Product::where('id', $product->id)->with('related', function($q) {
            $q->with('brand')->with('categories');
        })->with('brand')->first();

        return view('product', compact('product', 'category'));
    }
}
```

For some reason i get this error, which i don't understand why.

> BadMethodCallException **Call to undefined method App\Category::brands()**

Comment: Odd, I don't see `brands()` in your code here. Please post the stacktrace so we can see where the error lies. It might be in one of your models.

Comment: Are you calling `$category->brands` in your blade file by chance?

Comment: No i'm not, if i remove ```Brand $brand``` from the function it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route resolver is assuming the parameters are all related to each other. From [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-model-binding-scoping):

> When using a custom keyed implicit binding as a nested route parameter, Laravel will automatically scope the query to retrieve the nested model by its parent using conventions to guess the relationship name on the parent.

So you should have a `brands()` relationship set up in your `Category` model, as well as a `products()` relationship in your `Brand` model.

If it's not possible to set up a relationship, simply stop using the route model binding and do it manually:

```php
Route::get('/shop/{category}/{brand}/{product}', [ProductController::class, 'index']);
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Brand;
use App\Category;
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index(string $category, string $brand, string $product)
    {
        $category = Category::where('slug', $category);

        $product = Product::where('slug', $product)
            ->with(['category', 'brand'])->first();

        return view('product', compact('product', 'category'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand, but brands do not have a relationship with the categories, only products. 
So to fix this issue i should just use the slug and find the brand with a query inside the function.

Comment: Understood, one brand will have many products of different categories. Unfortunately the way the URL is set up, Laravel assumes a relationship. The docs don't mention any way to override or disable that behaviour.

Comment: Yes you could get rid of the route model binding altogether and do the lookups manually if you need the slugs in the URL instead of the ID. Although looking at your controller, you don't even use the `$category` or `$brand` variable.

Comment: I use ```$category``` in the compact function, i was just really confused with the error. 
Thanks for pointing it out!